# Github-hosted website looks different than when I locally download it

Tags: html, css, github, download, web

On my computer, my locally-hosted webpage looks like this:

However, when I pushed my webpage to GitHub, the entire site changes. The "Calendar" image gets bigger and my entire navigation bar shifts left and changes style:

I have two other pages on my website (The homepage and the contact page) and they are both working fine.

Does anybody else have the same problem?

Comment: Hi @Lara please include your code when asking a question :)

Comment: It's hard to debug this without a link or example code. Please add some! Chances are you're not referencing a CSS file correctly - the browser's web inspector may show errors that'll make it clearer.

Comment: Oh okay! My website is: larapalombi.github.io and the bug is under "calendar!"

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem in CSS code. Please check your CSS code. Or fix CSS code via Inspect in chrome browser. Or comment your site link

Comment: CSS doesn't change when its being moved from local to the server... unless you are using a different browser and/or haven't reset browser styles.

Comment: Yes i knew it @Remco